# Can I have a better precision for the .dot file I get out of scikit-learn for a decision tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am building a decision tree using scikit-learn and am exporting the resulting tree as a .dot file. However, the precision I am getting for each condition in each tree node is very low for numerical values. The numbers are rounded to four digits after the decimal point. Any ideas on how I could get better precision? Say 10 digits? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the [export_graphvis](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/export.py) function to change the %4f to just %f or any other precision. This function was meant for visualization, not really exchanging a predictor. There is a pull request with a json export IIRC, so if you want to store the tree to use it in another software, this might be more what you are looking for.